# .NET 6 Identity Customization - Error: There is no implicit reference conversion from ApplicationUser to IdentityUser<string>

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-6.0

I have customized all .NET 6 Identity model classes.  My setup was working just fine for over a year.  I updated to the latest .NET core identity libraries (6.0.7) and ran a new DB-Scaffold today, and all of a sudden, I'm getting the following error for ApplicationUser (plus the same error for the remainder of the custom Identity classes):

> CS0311    The type 'ApplicationUser' cannot be used
> as type parameter 'TUser' in the generic type or method
> 'IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserClaim, TUserRole,
> TUserLogin, TRoleClaim, TUserToken>'. There is no implicit reference
> conversion from 'ApplicationUser' to
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser'

I've got the EF database context configured as follows:

> `public partial class DatabaseContext  : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>`

My Identity classes are as follows:

> `public partial class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<string>`

> `public partial class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<string>`

This approach seems to be lined up with what Microsoft recommends here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0

I've tried everything I can think of but the errors are still coming up (tried changing over to a Guid instead of a string, for example).  I'm at a loss and hoping someone might be able to give me some advice on how to fix these errors?

Comment: have you done the Program.cs configurations? for example : `services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()`

Comment: Yes, I've moved all of the Identity configuration into an IdentityHostingStartup class:

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options => ...

Comment: why your classes are partial? it seems unusual

Comment: I removed 'partial' from them all and, unfortunately, same result.  Appreciate the suggestion.

Comment: you dont need to type 
`IdentityUser<string>` 
and 
 ` IdentityRole<string>`  
these are by default string. can you please try without `<string>` type parameter

Comment: Thanks.. I removed the "string" type from ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole - same result.

Comment: Could you please share how you add the identity inside the program.cs?

Comment: It has all been moved to a separate IdentityHostingStartup class:
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
    {
        public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options =>
                  ...                
                services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
                    { ....
                    })
                    .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
            });
        }

Answer (score 0):

This was due to the fact that I was still configured for the .NET 5 way of using Identity.  I created a new .NET 6 MVC project and migrated everything over to it, and that fixed the problem.